# Service-side breaking change from Microsoft causing WebException in Office Add-In

Tags: office-js, office-addins

This is just a good samaritan FYI to Microsoft, not a question to the community.

They have broken their VerificationServiceClient code with some server-side change that is causing VerificationServiceClient to throw an exception.  I've fixed my Office Add-In ASP.NET app in response to this break, but in order to help out others that may also be impacted by this I also wanted to surface it to Microsoft.

**Details:**

I've had an Office Add-In for Word in the Office App Store running successfully since 2014 without any code changes.  Recently, my app has spontaneously started crashing with 100% consistency, generating a WebException in the ASP.NET code with stack trace

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read
at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob
at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication
at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication
at System.Net.TlsStream.Write
at System.Net.PooledStream.Write
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read
```

which is coming from the source code that Microsoft provided to developers in 2014 to incorporate into their Office Add-In web apps for the purpose of verifying entitlements:

```
 VerificationServiceClient service = new VerificationServiceClient();
 VerifyEntitlementTokenRequest request = new VerifyEntitlementTokenRequest();
 request.EntitlementToken = decodedLicenseToken;
 VerifyEntitlementTokenResponse validationResponse = service.VerifyEntitlementToken(request);
```

Comment: What is your fix?